# Removing scrolling effect

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have this website - https://www.emeraldhill.rs/

On the home page, there is this part - https://prnt.sc/qp2ri0

If you click on any of these images it will take you to the page "Reference". Right after the page is loaded, depending on the position of the building you selected on the home page, it will start scrolling until it finds the right block. I set the anchor links. 
What I want is to avoid the scrolling part and land on the block that I choose on the home page instantly.

How can I achieve this?

The website is built with Divi theme.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollintoview

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  Some text inside an element.
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what you exactly need,and the referance link is provided above.
I gave you what you want in javascript.
I am not good in wordpress but i think you can edit divi theme.